# Check multiple HTML check boxes by value - bit twiddling

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, bit-manipulation

I have several checkboxes with the same name, and values that are a power of 2:

```
<input type=checkbox name=mycheckbox value=1>Some text 1
<input type=checkbox name=mycheckbox value=2>Some text 2
<input type=checkbox name=mycheckbox value=4>Some text 3
<input type=checkbox name=mycheckbox value=8>Some text 4
<input type=checkbox name=mycheckbox value=16>Some text 5
<input type=checkbox name=mycheckbox value=32>Some text 6
```

The value stored in the database is the bitwise **OR** of the selected checkboxes, so if Some text 3 and Some text 6 are checked, the value in the database will be `32 | 4 = 36`.

I load this value from the database using an Ajax call.  What would be the easiest or best way using jQuery to check the appropriate checkboxes based on the number?

I'm more used to doing scripting and would approach it like:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 32; i*=2)
   if ((ajaxValue & i) == i)
```

etc.

But ideally jQuery could do it much easier, and check the checkboxes by value.

Comment: CK - yes I am aware of basic exponent math.  The text Value 1 etc. was just replacement text for the business sensitive actual values.  I wasn't saying that 2^1 = a value of 1.  Have edited it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  $('input[name=mycheckbox]').each(function () {
    // Your code there like if ($(this).val() ....
    if ($(this).val() == someValue) $(this).attr('checked', 'checked'); // Example of make the checkbox checked
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Marian, I'll use this.  Note that the equality should be something like if (($(this).val()&someValue) > 0) or similar.

Answer (score 2):

`YOUR_VALUE` is coming from database.

```
$('input[name=mycheckbox][value="'+ YOUR_VALUE +'"]').prop('checked', true);
```

**According to your update question**

try this:

```
var x = [];

$('input[name=mycheckbox]').each(function() {
    x.push(this.value);
});
var len = x.length,
    target = 36; // this is the value you get from ajax (integer)

for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {
    for (j = len - 1; j > i; j--) {
        var value = x[j + i] | x[i];
        if ( value === target) {
            $('input[name=mycheckbox][value="' + x[i] + '"], 
               input[name=mycheckbox][value="' + x[j + i] + '"]')
           .prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
}
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ajFcf/1/)***

Comment: `prop` is recommended than `attr` to set `checked` property since it is a property of `checkbox` element.

Comment: Thanks but that won't solve the problem.  The value coming from the database is a bitwise-ORed value, and won't necessarily match any of the checkboxes.  As per the example, the database value is 36, but no checkbox has a value of 36.  A value of 36 means that value 4 and value 32 should be checked.